# Most effective text compression in PHP

Tags: php, text, compression

I'm working on a project that will be storing a lot of text files as a backup. I want it to compress somehow. At this time I'm using gzdeflate to compress files. Is there any more effective compress algorithm for text in PHP? No images etc will be involved.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By effective you mean in terms of storage space or CPU? There is a tradeoff there. At times a slightly better compression ratio can be way more expensive CPU wise.

Comment: By effective I mean less storage space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If by "effective" you mean size-wise then [`bzcompress()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bzcompress.php) will usually beat gzdeflate.